# Redux saga test select effect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, saga

How do I test select effect? My saga depends on the result of the select but each time I am just getting `undefined` from the saga.

Here is what I tried:

in my saga:

```
function* loadData() {
    const foo = yield select((state) => {
        return state.foo.value;
    });

    console.log('foo is :', foo);
}
```

in the test:

```
test.only('Data saga', t => {

    const generator = loadData();
    console.log(generator.next({foo: 'blah'}).value);
    console.log(generator.next());

});
```

but the result is `foo is : undefined`. How do I pass data to the default state please? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `const generator = ...; generator.next(); /*<- this is select effect descriptor*/ generator.next('bar'); /*<- this is you interpretator runnig select effect*/`?

Comment: This is a correct! Could you please post this as an answer? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach

```
test.only('Data saga', t => {

    const iterator = loadData();

    const selectFooValue = iterator.next(); // <-- this is effect descriptor

    // here you assert about selectFooValue

    const nextStep = iterator.next('bar'); // <-- this how you "running" select effect  

    // here you assert about nextStep

});
```